# Illegal String offset – how to use arrays instead?

Tags: php, arrays, string

This Code is giving me an illegal string offset for alt, sizes etc. I found some solutions for converting from string to array, but only within an if statement. I don't know much about php, sorry.

```
<?php
            $args = array( 'post_type' => 'shows', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' =>'title');
            $shows = new WP_Query( $args );
            $theTitle = get_field('collection_brand_name',$collection->ID);
            $tmpTitle =  str_replace(' ', '-', $theTitle);
            $newTitle =  str_replace('.', '-', $tmpTitle);
            foreach( $shows as $show ) :
                $image = get_field('shows_image',$show->ID);
                 // vars
                $alt = $image['alt'];
                // thumbnail
                $thumb = $image['sizes'][ $size ];
                $width = $image['sizes'][ $size . '-width' ];
                $height = $image['sizes'][ $size . '-height' ];

                //$image = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, $imgSize );
                $date = get_field('shows_date',$show->ID);
            endforeach;?>
```

Comment: That error happens when you apply `[]` to something that **is not** an array.

Comment: and how can i change it to an array?

Comment: You don't "change" it. You just make sure your variables actually contain what you think they do. It should be clear what variable it is since the error message should indicate the line number (you appear to have discarded that info).